# Is it possible to embed a neural network layer into decision tree/random forest?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, random-forest, decision-trees, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I want to do a classification task. I designed a customed layer for it. I also want to try decision tree/random forest, but as far as I know there is no way to embed my layer into a decsion tree/random forest and use backpropagation to train it. I can only use either decision tree/random forest or a neural network, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: would the NN be used in the leaves of the tree? But then there would be a large number of NNs to train, especially with random forests. I don't see how a NN and a decision tree can be combined?

Comment: @Erwan Yes as leaves. I can see it's impossible because they are non-parametric models.

Comment: the number of tree leaves is exponential, and NN tends to overfit (moreover if you have very less data, and in DecTree you have exp less data at each layer)... so I don't think that it's the way to go, and NN should absolutely not be the first thing that you think for a classifier... you might be astonished about how effective a LogRegression can be